# How do I properly disclose reference to my own project on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support

My answers are getting deleted when I post a screenshot and a link to my project.

Latest reason being:

> You've been warned about promoting your project before, especially without disclosure. Stop. Now.

What kind of disclosure is required in order to post code/screenshot/link from my project?

Comment: The help system [How to not be a spammer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion) has explicit advice. Are you paying attention to that?

Comment: It's actually a good question. Downvoting this question doesn't help anybody.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just make it clear in the text that it's yours. Preferably *before* you add the link and especially before the screenshot.

However, your problem may not be with attribution. If your answer is *nothing more* than a link/screenshot to your project, that's generally considered poor form. Link-only answers are bad form in principle, and being self-promotion isn't helping. You didn't post any examples, so I can only guess that this may be the case.