# Reason for closing an answer with legit-looking solution

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, link-only-answers

1. Someone posted a question with a mock-up of what they are trying to achieve.
2. Someone else developed a solution from that mock-up, put it up on GitHub as an Xcode project, and posted as an answer to the question.
3. Moderator deleted that answer.

I noticed it because the deleted answer is a sibling to my own answer. The deletion is unclear to me. If I were the OP of that question, I would definitely prefer the removed answer over the other one.

Here’s the deleted answer: [Custom position for each cell in CollectionView](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42050345/247441).

The code in the repo seems legit if not elegant, and is clearly too large to fit in answer body. I have only looked at it, though.

Is this an instance of inherent conflict between most question authors (who prefer answers containing specific code to address their immediate needs) and moderators (who prefer answers that share knowledge and therefore are more useful to the whole community)?

Or is there something else I am missing?

Comment: That answer is useless if that link dies.

Comment: @MikeM. a silent deletion implies harsh breach of some guideline.

Comment: Eh, not necessarily. Though you'd have to ask Martijn for a definite answer as to exactly why they deleted it.

Comment: @MikeM. there is no way to reach a moderator on SO after this action because comments on deleted posts are disabled.

Comment: Just an expression. Martijn'll probably see this post anyway.

Comment: The answer was flagged as Very Low Quality. Martijn agreed and removed it.

Comment: How do you "close" an answer?

Comment: *"there is no way to reach a moderator on SO after this action"* Marihn has 16,881 posts on the main page, so you have 16,881 ways to contact him.

Comment: @Tom Please don't leave random comments around the site to attract attention. Posting on Meta is the correct thing to do. Meta posts usually come to the attention of the correct mod one way or another. That doesn't mean that they personally have to respond; this case is pretty self evident and can (and has) been answered by anyone else.

Comment: @deceze That's strange, I often read (on meta iirc) that one is supposed to ping a user by writing a comment under one of his/her posts if the "source post" has been deleted.

Comment: @Tom I would not condone that practice. Comments are for commenting on the given post, not as a general chat board. Also, ideally you wouldn't ever need to ping a *specific person*. SO is not personality based, its only focus is content. If you have a dispute or question about how content was handled, Meta is it. The entire community can chime in on that. There should be absolutely no need trying to slug it out with one particular person.

Comment: @deceze I also agree that these cases are very limited, but if for example one writes a wrong answer and deletes it before I could explain specific issues, then I would explain that under one of his/her other posts and request a comment upvote to see that (s)he had read it, so I can remove the comment (or delete it after a few minutes). Using Meta just for that would be an overkill, imo.

Comment: @Tom Suuuure… but then again maybe you shouldn't be hunting down other people to correct them. They already deleted their post, perhaps they're already aware of their mistakes. I admire the effort, but you don't *have* to [edumucate each and every person.](https://xkcd.com/386/) ;)

Comment: Addressing “duplicate” marks: (1) http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288055/please-define-link-only-answer — no, the question here is about apparently silent deletion of link-only answer. (2) http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324027/how-do-i-properly-disclose-reference-to-my-own-project-on-stack-overflow — in this case it was not a plug for answerer’s project but a direct solution to OP’s mockup specifically AFAICS. (3) http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341163/minimum-bar-for-an-answer-not-to-be-classified-a-link-only-answer — same as (1).

Comment: I’m going claim that the issue of erroneously deleting answers into which authors invest effort has not been raised before and nominate this to be re-opened

Answer (score 9):

According to [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer):

> Provide context for links
>
> Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

So basically, the full code might be hosted on GitHub, but the crucial parts of it should be quoted in the answer or at least explain the details on Stack Overflow. The answers that rely on external content are *Low Quality*.

Comment: I am well aware of this guideline, thank you. However, I have never seen a silent deletion to be used to enforce any guideline save for abuse and spam. My question is specifically about deletion.

Comment: @Tony on [so] everything is silent deleted. Even comments.

Comment: @Tony, whilst reviewing answers I often left comments about low quality answers and flagged them as such. I found that the comment was often pointless as the answer was deleted very quickly with no way of the author seeing the comment. So now I just flag and move on (when it's clear that the answer does nothing to help the OP). I agree with what xenteros has said.

Comment: @Bugs I see, thanks for the clarification. I only did a bit of moderation a while ago so didn’t have a good picture of how the process usually works out.

Comment: My take-aways: due to proliferation of link-only answers that are junk, it’s natural to take shortcuts and use the quality of being “link-only” as a proxy measure of effort and value. In this case the answerer has apparently gone to remarkable lengths packaging a custom solution to OP’s mockup into an Xcode project and putting it up on GitHub, but did a poor job optics-wise, which resulted in a wrong but understandable deletion. (The community’s insistence that a guideline in ‘How to write a good answer’ was the sole grounds for deletion is still unclear to me, but IANAM.)

Comment: @Tony did you know that comment that the post is low quality will be deleted as "to chatty"?

Comment: @Tony it doesn't matter how much effort the poster put into doing something somewhere else. If [the answer is in the wrong castle](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer), it's in the wrong castle, simple as that. When evaluating answers we always assume that links are dead, because undoubtedly they will eventually be dead. If the answer is not an answer without the link, it is not an answer period.

Comment: @TinyGiant consider “How to write a good answer” vs. “If you don’t do this, your answer will be deleted without warning”

Comment: @Tony we explain both of those things not only in the help center and meta, but also in the form of comments under the answers prior to deletion in many cases. If a user decides to ignore all of this and post non-answers anyway, the consequences are on them, not us. The system does not notify any non-diamond users of content deletions or rep loss. This is to avoid complaints due to loss aversion.

Comment: @TinyGiant in this case no comment have been found (to my knowledge). I’m curious what processes were affecting community attitude in the past few years such that it became so much less tolerant of genuinely helpful but poorly-presented content.

Comment: Compare side by side previously existing answers [like this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5783933/247441) (which I’ve recently found and flagged as link-only) showing nothing more than a 30-second Googling and copy-pasting a few of the results, and the deleted answer with a link to an Xcode project created and published to GitHub solely to answer the question.

Comment: We can't keep up with the giant wall of crap that is constantly coming in, so some things are bound to slip through the cracks. Just because something has been missed, doesn't mean it's OK.